# Update parts list with new descriptions in excel

Tags: vba, excel, formula

Ive got two sheets. Each with about 20k part numbers, and I need to grab the part number from Sheet 1 col. B, check to see if it exists anywhere in Sheet 2 col.A, if it does then grab the contents of Sheet 2 col. B of that row, and paste it into the cell with the formula. the part numbers list doesn't match up 100% so I cant simply sort and copy/paste.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please specify what is the sheet and column of "the cell with the formula".

Comment: Can you show some examples of what you have tried?

Comment: From your description `VLOOKUP()` will do what you need.

Comment: The cell with the formula will be on sheet 1.

Comment: column C will be where the formula goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the example below:

```
Sub PopulateDescriptions()
    Dim objList As Object
    Dim objSrc As Range
    Dim objDst As Range
    Dim arrList() As Variant
    Dim arrDesc() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set objList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With Sheets("Sheet 2")
        arrList = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:B")).Value
    End With
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrList, 1)
        objList(arrList(i, 1)) = arrList(i, 2)
    Next

    With Sheets("Sheet 1")
        Set objSrc = Intersect(.UsedRange.Rows, .Range("A:A"))
    End With
    Set objDst = objSrc.Offset(0, 2) ' column C
    arrList = objSrc.Value
    arrDesc = objDst.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrList, 1)
        If objList.Exists(arrList(i, 1)) Then
            arrDesc(i, 1) = objList(arrList(i, 1))
        End If
    Next
    objDst.Value = arrDesc
End Sub
```

Comment: whoa! thanks, that worked perfectly!! thank you so much, I really appreciate your help!